Why is GCC warning me about overflow here?
The following program:
#include <algorithm>

char foo(char* buffer, unsigned int i, unsigned int buffer_size) {
    char c = 0;
    if (i == buffer_size) {
        std::copy(buffer + i, buffer + buffer_size, &c);
    }
    return c;
}

...generates the following warning when compiled with GCC with -O2 or -O3:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/algorithm:60,
                 from <source>:1:
In static member function 'static _Up* std::__copy_move<_IsMove, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_Tp*, _Tp*, _Up*) [with _Tp = char; _Up = char; bool _IsMove = false]',
    inlined from '_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = char*; _OI = char*]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:506:30,
    inlined from '_OI std::__copy_move_a1(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = char*; _OI = char*]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:533:42,
    inlined from '_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = char*; _OI = char*]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:540:31,
    inlined from '_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = char*; _OI = char*]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:633:7,
    inlined from 'char foo(char*, unsigned int, unsigned int)' at <source>:6:12:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:437:30: warning: 'void* __builtin_memcpy(void*, const void*, long unsigned int)' writing between 2 and 4294967295 bytes into a region of size 1 [-Wstringop-overflow=]
  437 |             __builtin_memmove(__result, __first, sizeof(_Tp) * _Num);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>: In function 'char foo(char*, unsigned int, unsigned int)':
<source>:4:14: note: destination object 'c' of size 1
    4 |         char c = 0;
      |              ^

What is going on here? Since i == buffer_size the std::copy shouldn't be copying anything here.
Compiler Explorer link

This is a warning. You've been warned your code is seen by the compiler as a red flag. It might be correct, but you've been warned.

@RichardCritten it should be a noop as i == buffer_size

It does appear to be a compiler bug, since the warning thinks the number of bytes to be copied is at least 2, which is false.

@NateEldredge I think it thinks the number of possible bytes is 0 - 2^32 but 0 and 1 are valid values so it warns that 2 - 2^32 are invalid values

i get often these warnings with Wstringop-overflow. I was never able to resolve them. It is unfortunately a flag that is was not befecial for me.

My question is why are you using this "C" style approach of passing data? C++ has either std::string, std::string_view. std::vectorstd::uint8_t or std::spanstd::uint8_t to manage the memory of all kinds of buffers.

@PepijnKramer I'd hope this is a minified part of some larger program, the code makes no sense as it is

@eyelash Ok, but then also tag your question with the version you can use (e.g. C++17). Small side note, for sizes don't use int, but use std::size_t

Might be regression\a flaw, if std::copy turns into __builtin_memmove, which uses a number of vodoo rituals and optimizations.

std::copy_n seems to be less problematic and also more idiomatic, https://godbolt.org/z/cq7xT6x9o

Looks like a bug, the compiler obviously realises at some point that the code doesn't do anything as it optimises it away. If you remove the if condition:
char foo(char* buffer, unsigned int i, unsigned int buffer_size) {
    char c = 0;
    std::copy(buffer + i, buffer + buffer_size, &c);
    return c;
}

you get exactly the same warning text. It's presumably performing the range check before it works out the code is redundant.
You could raise this as a bug on the GCC bug tracker.
If you rewrite the code to be slightly more sane then the warning goes away in GCC 14:
#include <algorithm>

char foo(char* buffer, unsigned int i, unsigned int buffer_size) {
    char c = 0;
    if (buffer_size - i == 1)
    {
        std::copy(buffer + i, buffer + i + 1, &c);
    }
    return c;
}


I think the range check is simply wrong, as it reports that the number of bytes copied is "between 2 and 4294967295 bytes".  Even in your example, it's entirely possible for that number to be 1 or 0, and the compiler seems to miss that possibility.  In OP's example, it actually is 0, and the compiler still misses it.

@NateEldredge 0 or 1 are valid values though so it doesn't warn about them

I still get the warning for your rewritten version: https://godbolt.org/z/Eocxej5sx

I think the compiler is unable to evaluate what buffersize is at compile time. It says, ok it can be anything betweer 0 .. max_int and the size of the destination is 1. So 2 - max int will exceed.

@ventsyv here is a version with a fixed size buffer: https://godbolt.org/z/6dxd5Kz4o

@eyelash That will still not evaluate. The compiler doesn't know what the value of i is. It would be any valid uint. If you make i a const expression, I bet it will work.

@eyelash ah, I was using a more recent GCC

@AlanBirtles On GCC 14 my original example will also work if I replace unsigned int with long unsinged int or size_t.

Your destination (c) is of size 1. The compiler doesn't know what buffer_size is at compile time. It assumes it can be anything between 0 - MAX_INT thus anything exceeding your destination buffer size is an overflow.
I bet something like will work:
constexpr uint buffer_size = 5;
constexpr uint i = 4;
buffer [buffer_size] = "test";

foo(buffer, i, buffer_size);

These constant expressions will evaluate at compile time and the compiler will "realize" what you are copying will fit in the destination and the warning will disappear.
But this is not very useful, because in real life you want to use runtime values...

Your code doesn't even compile.

@eyelash It's just a demo. You have to pay for the full version.
